# Query with EXISTS for Doctrine Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

How can I implement the following query with Query Builder?

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE t.status = 1
    OR EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM r 
              WHERE r.t_id = t.id 
                  AND r.status = 1
             )
```

The part without exist check is easy, but is there a way to implement the `EXISTS`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You either need to use two query builders:

```
$queryBuilder->expr()->exists($subQueryBuilder->getDql());
```

or use DQL directly:

```
$queryBuilder->expr()->exists('SELECT * 
    FROM r 
    WHERE r.t_id = t.id 
    AND r.status = 1'
);
```

You'll find more examples in the docs: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/query-builder.html

**Note:** You have to set parameters in the **main** query, even though they're used in the exists (Thanks [Vadim Ashikhman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771556/vadim-ashikhman)).

Comment: Is it possible to bind parameters in the subquery? (your link is dead)

Comment: You have to set parameters in the main query even those that are used in the `exists` statement.