# Top level EXISTS query using Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a query such as this in plain SQL (of course the original is more complex, but still simple enough that I'm quite sure that that part is correct at least):

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE 1 = 1)
```

The question is: How do I do this using Doctrine ORM DQL?

My current state looks as follows:

```php
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$subQueryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

$subQueryBuilder
    ->select('1')
    ->from(MyEntity::class, 'b')
    ->where($subQueryBuilder->expr()->eq('1', '1'))
;

return (bool) $queryBuilder
    ->select('EXISTS(' . $subQueryBuilder->getDQL() . ')')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult()
;
```

This will throw a parsing error, as EXISTS is an unknown function (and there is no built-in function to cover this). Using a native query didn't work either, but I might have messed this up, so am grateful for a correct example including a result set mapping.

There are answers for similar questions on SO, but I haven't found this exact problem.

- [Query with EXISTS for Doctrine Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030538/query-with-exists-for-doctrine-symfony2) (answers the case where EXISTS is used in the WHERE part)
- [Doctrine2 DBAL Exists query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140768/doctrine2-dbal-exists-query) answers the right question but only for Doctrine DBAL, not ORM.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, despite feeling a bit wrong, I solved the problem by using a native query. Here it is for reference (still open for improvement though):

```php
$subQueryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

$subQueryBuilder
    ->select('1')
    ->from(MyEntity::class, 'b')
    ->where($subQueryBuilder->expr()->eq('foo', '?'))
;

$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->em);
$rsm->addScalarResult('x', 'x', 'boolean');

$query = $this->em
    ->createNativeQuery('SELECT EXISTS(' . $subQueryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL() . ') as x', $rsm)
;

return (bool) $query
    ->setParameter(1, 'bar')
    ->getSingleScalarResult()
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a bit better way and it supports complex criterias also

```
protected function existsBy(array $criteria): bool
{
    $entityPersister = $this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister($this->entityClass);
    $subSql = $entityPersister->getSelectSQL($criteria);
    $subSql = \preg_replace('/^(SELECT).*(FROM)/', '$1 1 $2', $subSql);

    [$params, $types] = $entityPersister->expandParameters($criteria);

    return $this->entityManager->getConnection()
        ->executeQuery('SELECT EXISTS(' . $subSql . ')', $params, $types)
        ->fetchOne();
}
```

Where `$this-entityClass` is a FQCN of the class, like `Entity::class`